# Automatically apply fill colour conditional upon row by row comparison of two columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I have two Excel columns of numerical natural values and of the same length.
For each row I would like to fill the cells with red if the values are different, with green if they are equal.

I thought I could do this using Conditional Formatting but it seems it is not fit to compare two columns.

Am I wrong? How can I do that? How to use an IF statement for this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the values are in column A and B

To create the first rule:

1. Select columns A an B. Do this by dragging from column header A to
   B.
2. Then, click Home > Conditional Formatting > New Rule.
3. In the New Formatting Rule dialog box, click Use a formula to
   determine which cells to format.
4. Under Format values where this formula is true, type the formula:
   `=$A1=$B1`
5. Click Format.
6. Select a green fill color.
7. Click OK until the dialog boxes are closed.

The formatting is applied to column A and B.

Now you can create a second rule for `=$A1<>$B1` with red fill color.

Answer (score 0):

A "cheat" (if your columns are not too long) is to transpose your two columns, then use CF's Highlight Cells Duplicate Values rule (but change the default colours to suit) and transpose back again. It may be a slight advantage of this transposition that formatting will not be applied to cells in the same row that are both blank (though easy enough to arrange for this with a formula rule).

The point of my answering however is really to say that you only need **one** rule. Since every cell is going to be either red or green using `standard` formatting for one format is sufficient. For example, fill your entire data set with 'standard' green fill and then apply a formula rule for red. This will happily override the 'standard' green fill where appropriate.

If applied to Range $A:$B (such as by first selecting ColumnsA:B) I suggest a formula rule of:

```
=AND(A1<>"",$A1=$B1)
```

You do not need an IF statement because the formatting is *conditional* (the IF is implicit).

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your data is in columns A and B, first select the column you want to colorize.

Then for the green :
Conditionnal Formatting > New Rule > Use Formula to determine... > type formula : =(A1=B2) 
Then Click the Format... button and choose Green color

And for the red : 
Conditionnal Formatting > New Rule > Use Formula to determine... > type formula : =(A1<>B2) 
Then Click the Format... button and choose Red color